# Is it possible connect Jupyter-Kernel-Gatewy with JupyterHub or Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I was playing with Jupyter, JupyterHub and Jupyter-Kernel-Gateway. I made some Notebooks and Kernels in Jupyter and i can connect to them by JupyterHub.
For another try, i want to connect them from the Kernel-Gateway. Is this possible?

Comment: Jupyter-kernel-gateway only manages *kernels*, which are typically individual `ipython` processes running code snippets. So the answer is No. You should use a Notebook to connect to a kernel-gateway which manages a pool of kernels. See this [post](https://blog.jupyter.org/on-demand-notebooks-with-jupyterhub-jupyter-enterprise-gateway-and-kubernetes-e8e423695cbf) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This makes the structure more clear for me.
Is it necessary to use JupyterLab?

Comment: It's not necessary.